# Level $\vartheta$ of distribution of primes

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, definition

I have read many papers where the following is written:

•If the level $\vartheta$ of distribution of primes exceeds $1/2$...

•If the level $\vartheta$ of distribution of primes is equal to $1/2$...

I have no idea what this concept refers to and why it is sometimes assumed $\vartheta =1/2$ and other times $\vartheta>1/2$. Can someone explain to me the origin of this?  or any reference that I can understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This notion originated from the prime number theorem in arithmetic progressions.

### PNT and Siegel-Walfisz theorem

Let $\pi(x;q,a)$ denote the number of elements in

$$
\{p\le x:p\text{ prime},p\equiv a\pmod q\}
$$

Then the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions states that when $(a,q)=1$ there is

$$
\pi(x;q,a)\sim{\pi(x)\over\varphi(q)},\tag1
$$

where $\pi(x)=\pi(x;1,1)$ denotes the number of primes $\le x$. Initially, mathematicians were able to prove that (1) holds for all $(a,q)=1$ provided that $q$ is fixed. However, this would be insufficient when $q$ is allowed to vary with $x$. As a result, in the early 20th century, mathematicians began investigating the error terms of (1). i.e.

$$
E(x,q)=\max_{(a,q)=1}\left|\pi(x;q,a)-{\pi(x)\over\varphi(q)}\right|.
$$

In 1935, Siegel and Walfisz proved that for any fixed $A>0$ there is a constant $C_1(A)>0$ such that $E(x,q)<C(A)x(\log x)^{-A}$, which indicates that (1) holds whenever $q\le(\log x)^A$. Although $\log x$ is quite small compared to any power of $x$, this is sufficient for us to deduce the ternary Goldbach conjecture (i.e. every sufficiently large odd integer is a sum of 3 primes).

### Summing over the errors

Due to difficulties in studying the properties of Dirichlet L-functions, instead of estimating individual $E(x,q)$, mathematicians decide to estimate the sum over it instead:

$$
S(x,Q)=\sum_{q\le Q}E(x,q)
$$

In 1947, A. Rényi proved that there exists some $\eta>0$ such that

$$
\forall A>0,\exists C_2(A)>0\text{ s.t. }\forall x\ge2,S(x,x^\eta)<C_2(A)x(\log x)^{-A}\tag2
$$

This allows him to conclude that there exists some $C>0$ such that every large even integer is a sum of a prime and a number with at most $C$ prime factors (aka proposition 1+C).

Now, let $\mathcal B$ denote the set of $\eta>0$ for (1) to hold and $\vartheta=\sup\mathcal B$. Then $\vartheta$ is called the **level of distribution of primes**, so Rényi basically proves that $\vartheta>0$, which results in a large $C$ in proposition 1+C. In 1965, A. I. Vinogradov and E. Bombieri showed that $\vartheta\ge\frac12$, yielding proposition 1+3 (i.e. every large even integer is a sum of a prime and a number with at most 3 prime factors). This is the best result till this day, and Chen's proposition 1+2 follows from improvements in other aspects.

### The level of distribution in modern papers

With these historical backgrounds in mind, we can explain why this concept is used in modern papers concerning number theory.

In 2009, Goldston, Pintz, and Yildirim proved that when $\vartheta>\frac12$ (i.e. (2) holds for some $\eta>\frac12$), there exists some constant $C_3(\vartheta)>0$ such that

$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}(p_{n+1}-p_n)<C_3(\vartheta).
$$

After a careful analysis, one finds out that $C_3(\vartheta)$ turns out to be smaller when $\vartheta$ is larger. Therefore, improvements in the lower bound for $\vartheta$ can lead to improvements in the study of small gaps between primes.

Comment: What value of $\vartheta$ is needed to get $C_{3}(\vartheta)=20$?